# Visual Studio Code white space after running command in terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

Keep having this issue in vs code with the terminal.
Whenever I enter a enter a command,the terminal just jumps down many white spaces.
Not to mention I can not even enter the input.
Found something on this being a terminal rendering issue but not any solution to it.
The terminal works but only I make it as big as possible in the vs code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTgSL.png

Are there any solutions to this?

Comment: If this happens for any command you run, it might just be your prompt variable (`$PS1`). Does it happen outside of VS Code in Git Bash or in other terminal emulators using your Bash login shell?

Comment: @user Tried it with some other code and with git bash outside.Same,when I press enter it just jumps down a bunch of space.
Seems it only works correctly if I maximize the git bash window.

Comment: what's do you see when you `echo $PS1`? Can you edit your post to show us the output?

Comment: @user Found some info on this being a windows build issue,so I'm gonna try and update.